# How to set 300 dpi resolution in embedded image in svg vector image

Tags: inkscape, pdf, svg

I have SVG vector image with embedded raster image i need to set resolution for embedded raster image as 300 dpi resolution using command line.

Comment: You can't. Inkscape is a vector image editor. It can't edit raster images.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, jaigan. Have you tried to setting 300 dpi in document preferences, then using [Make a Bitmap Copy](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Copy.html) on your raster image (see also [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/optimize-bitmap-images-within-inkscape/86832)) before performing command line export? Can you tell us something more about your file, e.g. it is generated by an application?